# Angular Services variable with RxJs value is correct but on function call is null

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have this service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class BackgroundLayersService {
  private mapSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Map | null>(null);
  map$: Observable<Map | null> = this.mapSubject.asObservable();

  constructor(private mapService: MapService) {
    this.mapService.map$.subscribe((map: Map | null) => {
      console.log('Map updated in BackgroundLayersService:', map);
      this.mapSubject.next(map);
    });
  }

  public map: Map | null;

  changeLayer(input: any) {
    console.log('test');
    console.log(this.map);
    }
}
```

Which loads a "map" from another service, this is the other service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MapService {
  constructor(private store: Store) {
  }
  @ViewChild('mapId') mapContainer: ElementRef;

  private mapSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Map | null>(null);
  map$ = this.mapSubject.asObservable();

  initializeMap(): void {
    this.setMap(
      L.map('mapId', {
        layers: [],
      }).setView([1, 1], 6)
    );
  }
}
```

When setMap is called, the first service's constructor console logs the correct value.
However when changeLayer is called, the console log shows the value of map to be null.

I don't understand why this is, and I can't seem to pass this map value to other components or services. Would appreciate any help.

Relevant Info: this.map is updated with the correct value before changeLayer is called.

initializeMap sets the map:

```
initializeMap(): void {
    this.setMap(
      L.map('mapId', {}
    );
  }
```

happens here:

```
init = () => {
    this.mapService.initializeMap();

    this.mapService.map$.subscribe((map) => {
      this.mapInstance = map;
    });
}
```

and here the value of map from subscribe is also correct, later within the component the value of map is used and is not null.

Comment: How is `setMap()` defined? The code you posted does not set `this.map` anywhere.

Comment: As far as I can see BackgroundLayerService.map is never reassigned and therfore alsways `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer guys, turns out was that the service was a singleton as declared with the following annotation on the service.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
```

However it wasnt always a singleton, as such there was a provider left over in the standalone component containing this service, meaning that even if the service was a singleton and could be reused, meaning that an extra version was created just for this standalone component.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: your answer is strange. The fact that it's a standalone component should not affect the service, it should still be only one single instance. but anyway, happy that it works now

Comment: I spent like two days trying to figure out the issue, in the end all I did was this. Could well be that I fixed other stuff along the way, but 100% removing it from the provider is what finally got it to finally work.

Answer (score 1):

as commented by Chund, `this.map` is alway null and you never reassign it.
Maybe you should use `this.mapSubject.getValue()` instead or you have to assign `map` for example like this:

```js
this.mapService.map$.subscribe((map: Map | null) => {
  this.map = map;
  this.mapSubject.next(map);
});
```

keep in mind that subscribing to an observable and then emitting a value is considered bad practice. Should try to concatenate your observable i.e. with `switchMap` or in this vase merge them maybe with `merge()`